# Insert data into database using react and node.js error

Tags: javascript, mysql, reactjs, node.js

I have a problem. when I try to insert data into the database it works and usually page does not refresh, but when I try to upload images too, images upload but the data does not insert into the database, and the page refreshes (It is not normal):

react.js:
https://github.com/worldremo/Top_Gardering/blob/main/client/src/views/Home.jsx

node.js/express.js
https://github.com/worldremo/Top_Gardering/blob/main/server/index.js

Comment: This is my updated question:
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663056/insert-data-into-database-and-upload-foles-using-react-js-and-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663056/insert-data-into-database-and-upload-foles-using-react-js-and-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

your issue might be because you're handling the finally part in a bit of a funky way. That thing is like a backup team that comes into play no matter how the game is going, but it seems like you're passing setLoading(false) as if it were a direct starting player, and that could be causing some confusion.

So, to fix this mess, you gotta wrap setLoading(false) inside some kind of package, like a group of friends always helping each other out. Here's how it could look:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/postsapi')
        .then(response => { setPosts(response.data) })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // Put setLoading(false) inside a crew of anonymous functions

    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/galleryapi")
        .then(response => setGallery(response.data))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
        .finally(() => setLoading(false)); // Put setLoading(false) inside a crew of anonymous functions
}, []);
```

Oh, and it would be cool to handle errors in a more chill way, like showing an error message or kind of logging the error to better understand what might be going wrong. Check out these changes and see if they sort out the dilemma. If the trouble continues, peek at your browser's console to see if there are errors from that side, and also look at the server logs for any hiccups during the image loading.

Comment: But the reason why data is not inserting into the database while uploading images into the folder maybe this?

Comment: The problem may be with how you are handling requests to the server when uploading images. In the current implementation of your code, it appears that you are calling setLoading(false) for both requests regardless of which completes first. This could lead to problems as setLoading(false) will be called even if only one of the requests (for example, the one for images) has completed.

Comment: so, is it better to set loading only on posts or only on images?

Comment: Okay thank you very much!

Comment: This code could be a lot simpler if using `async` is an option here.

Comment: This is my updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77663056/insert-data-into-database-and-upload-foles-using-react-js-and-node-js